# Explicit description of $X \to K(\pi_1(X),1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

Let $X$ be a Cw complex basepointed at $x$.  Delooping the covering fibration gives the fibration I'm interested $X \to K(\pi_1(X),1)$ with homotopy fiber $\tilde{X}$.

The explicit construction works by turning $X \to K(\pi_1(X),1)$ into a fibration:  The total space is the paths in $K(\pi_1(X),1)$ starting somewhere in $X$.  The projection map sends a path to its endpoint.

The fiber is the paths in $K(\pi_1(X),1)$ starting somewhere in $X$ and ending at $x \in X$.

We can explicitly see that the constructed fiber is homotopy equivalent to $\tilde{X}$(this viewpoint is useful when describing the monodromy action).  Here is the correspondence.  Take a path $\gamma$ in the constructed fiber.  The path is homotopic relative the start and endpoint to a path lying completely in $X$(b/c $\pi_1(X)=\pi_1(K(\pi_1,1))$).  Uniquely lift the path so that the endpoint is lifted to the basepoint of $\tilde{X}$.  Record the starting point of the path.

**Question: What is the map from $\tilde{X}$ to the fiber?**

Comment: I don't think there's any particularly "natural" map from $\tilde{X}$ to the fiber; as far as I can see the map is really only naturally defined up to coherent homotopy.  Specifically, constructing it involves choosing a nullhomotopy of the composition of $\tilde{X}\to X$ with $X\to K(\pi_1(X),1)$ (and how "explicit" you can make this depends on exactly how you are defining the map $X\to K(\pi_1(X),1)$).

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I will think about what you said overnight.  I was looking for a homotopy inverse of the map I wrote down above. The model for $K(\pi_1,1)$ I had in mind was that obtained by attaching cells.  I know how to write an explicit homotopy here.