# Why is $S^\infty \times_{\mathbb{Z}/2} S^2 \sim RP^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\RP}{\mathbb{RP}}$
Let $S^\infty$ be given the canonical $\pi_1(\RP^2)=Z/2$-equivariant cell structure.

I am trying to see why the map $S^\infty \times_{\mathbb{Z}/2} \tilde{RP^2}  \to pt \times_{\Z/2} S^2=\RP^2$ is a homotopy equivalence.

My motivation is in finding a more explicit model for the map $X \to K(\pi_1(X),1)$ for $X$ a CW complex.(see [Explicit description of $X \to K(\pi_1(X),1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885697/explicit-description-of-x-to-k-pi-1x-1))

I am posting the question because it does not follow from $S^\infty$ being contractible. This is because there is no action of $\pi_1$ on $r_t(S^\infty)$ where $r_t$  is the $t$th stage of the retraction.

Comment: Sorry about the grammar edits.  But nothing irritates me more when stackexchange questions are not written in proper English.

Answer (score 1):

You have a fiber bundle $S^\infty \to (S^\infty \times_{\Bbb Z/2} S^2) \to (* \times_{\Bbb Z/2} S^2)$. The fiber is contractible, so the last map is at least a weak homotopy equivalence; indeed it's an actual homotopy equivalence by Whitehead's theorem.

Comment: Thanks.  One idea:  I can use an explicit local trivialization of the fiber bundle to find an explicit retraction.  (It will turn into the same proof that any vector bundle is homotopy equivalent to the base).  I'll try turning this into an answer.